# How do you represent MS-DTYP `DATETIME` in Java 8 Instant?

Tags: java, c#, time, datetime-conversion, java.time.instant

In the Microsoft Spec, `DATETIME` is represented as 2 32-bit integers: `low` and `high`

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/cca27429-5689-4a16-b2b4-9325d93e4ba2

> The FILETIME structure is a 64-bit value that represents the number of
>   100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 1601,
>   Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). typedef struct _FILETIME { DWORD
>   dwLowDateTime; DWORD dwHighDateTime; } FILETIME,
>   *PFILETIME,
>   *LPFILETIME; dwLowDateTime: A 32-bit unsigned integer that contains the low-order bits of the file time. dwHighDateTime: A 32-bit unsigned
>   integer that contains the high-order bits of the file time.

For example, here is the long `130280867040000000`

So the the high and low computed with

```
int high = (int)(fullval >> 32);
int low = (int)fullval;
```

so high = `30333378`
and low = `552794112`

How do I compute these to a Java 8 Instant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For converting with 1 second precision your own answer is just fine. In case you also need to convert the fraction of second, here’s one way to do that.

```
    Instant msFiletimeEpoch = Instant.parse("1601-01-01T00:00:00Z");
    // a tick is 100 nanoseconds
    int nanosPerTick = 100;
    long ticksPerSecond = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1) / nanosPerTick;

    long fullval = 130_280_867_040_000_000L;

    long seconds = fullval / ticksPerSecond;
    long nanos = fullval % ticksPerSecond * nanosPerTick;

    Instant answer = msFiletimeEpoch.plusSeconds(seconds).plusNanos(nanos);

    System.out.println(answer);
```

Output is:

> 2013-11-05T00:58:24Z

Let’s try to put 1 more tick on your oroginal value; it should add 100 nanoseconds.

```
    long fullval = 130_280_867_040_000_001L;
```

> 2013-11-05T00:58:24.000000100Z

So so it does.

Caveat for very far future dates: According to your quote the Microsoft integers are both unsigned. A Java `long` is signed. So some time in year 30828 we will start getting results that are very wrong. Just in case we ought to throw an exception if the `long` value is negative.

Answer (score 2):

Ah I was barking up the wrong tree when I split the bytes in half like that.

Basically it's just saying that the units are in 100ns.

And the Epoch has a different base time too. So you have to add the offset as well.

So it is:

```
    private static final long DATETIME_EPOCH_DIFF_1601;
    static {
        LocalDateTime time32Epoch1601 = LocalDateTime.of(1601, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0);
        Instant instant = time32Epoch1601.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
        DATETIME_EPOCH_DIFF_1601 = (instant.toEpochMilli() - Instant.EPOCH.toEpochMilli()) / 1000;
    }
    Instant answer = Instant.ofEpochSecond(fullval / 10000000 + DATETIME_EPOCH_DIFF_1601)
```

Comment: From your sample value your code prints 2013-11-05T00:58:24Z. This agrees perfectly with [SiliSoftware Date format converter](https://www.silisoftware.com/tools/date.php?inputdate=130280867040000000&inputformat=filetime). It seems you are not converting any fraction of second; I’m sure that could be done if needed.